# Three.js select object with camera, no mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, raycasting

in a Three.js app I want to get the object that the perspective camera is pointing at and to do that I read the raycaster docs.
All the docs that I found talk about doind raycasting with camera and a Vector2 from the mouse coordinates, but I don't want to use the 2d coordinates of the mouse. The camera can rotate for any reason: click and drag the screen, touch control or even VR control, I just want to raycast from the center point of the perspective camera and set as "selected" the object it looks at.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`THREE.Raycaster.set()` expects `origin` and a `direction` vectors:

> origin — The origin vector where the ray casts from.
>
> direction — The direction vector that gives direction to the ray. Should be normalized.

Set the cameras world position as `origin` and its world direction as `direction`:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

raycaster.set( camera.getWorldPosition(), camera.getWorldDirection() );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objectsArray );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from Falk still works but Three.js (>r90) requires you to define a target [1]:

> target is now required

All you have to do is:

```
let camera_world_pos = new THREE.Vector3();
let camera_world_dir = new THREE.Vector3();
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

camera.getWorldPosition(camera_world_pos);
camera.getWorldDirection(camera_world_dir);
raycaster.set(camera_world_pos, camera_world_dir);
let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objectsArray );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    //...
}
```

[1] https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12231